# UE4 C++: Can't move Actor in circular path

Tags: c++, animation, graphics, unreal-engine4, game-development

I am using Unreal Engine 4.25. I am trying to move an Actor, which is a sphere, in a circular path. However the sphere only moves back and forth in a straight line.

Here is MyActor.cpp code:

```
#include "MyActor.h"
#include "Materials/MaterialInstanceDynamic.h" 
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

// Sets default values
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;



    Root = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
    RootComponent = Root;

    Mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
    Mesh->AttachTo(Root);

    Dimensions = FVector(30, 0, 0);
    AxisVector = FVector(0.01, 0.01, 0);
    Location   = FVector(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    Multiplier = 50.f;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
}

// Called every frame
void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    // Updates the angle of the object
    AngleAxis += DeltaTime * Multiplier;

    if (AngleAxis >= 360.0f)
    {
        AngleAxis = 0;
    }

    //Rotates around axis
    FVector RotateValue = Dimensions.RotateAngleAxis(AngleAxis, AxisVector);

    Location.X += RotateValue.X;
    Location.Y += RotateValue.Y;
    Location.Z += RotateValue.Z;

    SetActorLocation(Location, false, 0, ETeleportType::None);

}
```

Please let me know if I need to add any more information.

Disclaimer: I am completely new to UE4. My apologies if it is a dumb question.

Comment: `AxisVector` is very small. try a normalized vector. Also you should probably use `RotateValue` directly, not accumulate it in `Location`.

Comment: @Rotem, I've tried larger values of AxisVector, they give the same result. Is there a built in function for normalization?

Comment: There is `GetSafeNormal()` but it kinda looks to me like you're trying to rotate around the `0,0,1` or `0,1,0` axes, based on your dimensions vector only having an X component.

Comment: @Roten it worked after removing the location variable and using RotateValue instead worked.